How to render JPEG stored in S3 bucket in RShiny
I am trying to read in a JPEG hosted on an S3 bucket inside an RShiny app I have developed. So far, the only luck I have had is manually downloading the image and rendering the image using imageOutput()/renderImage(). I would like to do something more programmatic.
I have tried a few things. Firstly:
bucket_name <- "mybucket/images"
object_key <- "myimage.jpeg"
image1 <- aws.s3::s3read_using(FUN = jpeg::readJPEG,
                           native = TRUE,
                           object = object_key,
                           bucket = bucket_name)

This generates a large nativeRaster object which I have displayed in the viewport using
grid::grid.raster(image1). However I have not been able to think of a way to actually render this in shiny. While not ideal, I would even be open to saving this image somehow and then rendering the locally saved version.
I have also tried to use the get_object() function from aws.s3 which results in a large raw object: aws.s3::get_object(object_key, bucket_name), but I have been unable to successfully translate this raw object to a rendered image in RShiny.
I appreciate any ideas you may have, thank you!
EDIT with Solution: I went with Mikko's solution and used save_object() to simply save the image into a folder which was read in via renderImage().

Rendering the output of get_object() is possible, however, difficult to try if one has no access to some bucket. Could you provide the returned raw object of get_object() for an example image? E.g. using dput()?

Have you tried save_object() with renderImage()?

Thank you both! I actually went with your solution @MikkoMarttila and it worked perfectly, I was not aware of the save_object() function.

I went with Mikko's solution and used save_object() to simply save the image into a folder which was read in via renderImage().
